# Filtering models that belong to other models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, filter

I've got two models: `ProductCategory` and `Product`. `Product` model belongs to `ProductCategory`, and product category can have many products accordingly. The case is that I need to implement some kind of filter that would return me `Product`s that belong to specific `ProductCategory`. These are my models:

```
class ProductCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product_category

  # Here I added some kind of filter method 
  # But I haven't managed how to use it yet

  def self.filter(filter)
    where(product_category_id: filter) if filter
  end
end
```

And in my controller I added something like this:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    if params[:product]
      @products = Product.filter(params[:product][:product_category]
    else
      @products = Product.all
    end
  end
end
```

But I can't actually manage how to use my filter and I guess I should refactor it a lot. Can anyone help me with that, please?

Comment: I would recommend to use scope instead of class method.

Comment: Why do you need a filter if you have the association? You can fetch `category.products`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `params[:product][:product_category]` is the ProductCategory **ID**.

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    if params[:product]
      @category = ProductCategory.find(params[:product][:product_category])
      @products = @category.products
    else
      @products = Product.all
    end
  end
end
```

If `params[:product][:product_category]` anything else than **ID** then use `find_by` instead of `find`.